# Removing excess "tail" from an svg enclosing an image

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a png logo that I'm enclosing in a circle svg.
When making the image big enough i see that theres alot of excess whitespace.

I'm new to svg and have tried to resize it in every all the ways i can find but that ens up costing image quality or size. I've tried putting the svg in a div container and resizing the div without any success. The enclosed image is 940 x 940px.

```
<div class="container" style="height:10%;width:100%; display:block;">
    <svg id="graph" class="text-center" width="100%" height="3500px" display="block">

        <defs>
            <pattern id="image" x="0%" y="0%" height="100%" width="100%"
                     viewBox="0 0 350 420">
                <a href="index.html">
                    <image x="0%" y="0%" width="512" height="512" xlink:href="img/CheesyTools2.png"></image>
                </a>
            </pattern>
        </defs>

        <circle id="sd" class="medium" cx="50%" cy="5%" r="5%" fill="url(#image)" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5%" />
        <text text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="11%" style="color:#274666; font-size:40px;">CheesyTools</text>
        <text text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="12%" style="color:#274666; font-size:20px;">The world's leading website in being useless.</text>

    </svg>
</div>
```

Image showing the logo:

[image]

I get that the excess whitespace comes from the 3500px height but that was the only way i could get the logo to be in an appropriate size for the site.
I would like to have it in the same size but without all the excess height.

Sincerely, a noob.

Comment: (FYI, this doesn’t necessarily need SVG in the first place - formatting the image itself with a `border-radius` can achieve the same effect …)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made quite a few changes in your SVG. instead of the width and height of your SVG I'm using a `viewBox` attribute. The SVG is not as big as it was, it's just the size you need for the image and the text. Now is easier to work with with your SVG and put it where ever you need in the page. I hope it helps.

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 365px;
  height: 380px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg id="graph" class="text-center" viewBox="245 45 365 380" display="block">

        <defs>
            <pattern id="image" x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%">
                <a href="index.html">
                    <image width="260" height="260" xlink:href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/beagle400.jpg"></image>
                </a>
            </pattern>
        </defs>
 
        <circle id="sd" class="medium" cx="430.75" cy="175.075" r="127.5" fill="url(#image)" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" />
        <text text-anchor="middle" x="430.75" y="370" style="color:#274666; font-size:40px;">CheesyTools</text>
        <text text-anchor="middle" x="430.75" y="400" style="color:#274666; font-size:20px;">The world's leading website in being useless.</text>
  
    </svg>
```

Comment: This worked like a charm, tweaked the css a bit and its perfect!
Thank you so much enxaneta!